# Summarize LDA output using PCA

Tags: pca, latent-dirichlet-alloc

According to the perplexity' score, optimal number of topics for my dataset is 100. Once I run my LDA algorithm, I'd like to input those topics into an OLS but 100 independent variables is too much. My idea was to summarize them using a PCA (or t-sne) but i'm not so sure if I can given LDA is already a dimension reduction technic. Would you have any suggestions in that regard ? Thanks

Comment: You've omitted to explain the goal of these analyses. With that caveat, why not re-run the LDA with the number of topics you want to have as input to the regression?

Comment: @dipetkov The goal is to measure a financial score (dependent var.) given a number of control variables and those 100 topics (ind. var.). I computed an optimal number of 100 topics using the perplexity score, does using a smaller number of topics for the LDA would be rigorous ?

Comment: Not any less rigorous perhaps than first doing LDA and then PCA. Keep in mind that there is a difference between topic modeling as final goal of the analysis, and topic modeling to generate features as input to another model.